# InStr returns 1 when used with an empty string

Tags: vb6

I'm working on migrating some old VB6 code to C# at the moment, I've been testing my C# code against the VB code to check that the counterpart methods in each language return the same value.

I'm having problems with this if statement:

```
If InStr(1, "LPTVJY", strTempTaxCode) <> 0 Then
  strTempTaxCode = "0" & strTempTaxCode
End if
```

When  `strTtempTaxCode = ""` The value `1` is returned from the `InStr(1, "LPTVJY", strTempTaxCode)` call. Why is this? As far as I am aware I should be returned `0` as none of the characters from `"LPTVJY"` are within `strTempTaxCode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*All* strings of nonzero length, including single-character strings,  contain the empty string.

```
Debug.Print InStr("abc", "")     ' => 1
Debug.Print InStr("a", "")       ' => 1
Debug.Print "abc" & "" = "abc"   ' => True
```

If you have trouble wrapping your head around the concept, consider that all numbers have a factor of 1:

```
' (not a real function)
Debug.Print Factors(2)           ' => 1, 2
Debug.Print 2 * 1 = 2            ' => True
```

This is known as the *Multiplicative Identity Property*. You can think of strings as having a similar identity property involving the empty string.

If you don't want `InStr()` to match the empty string, do a preliminary test before calling it:

```
If Len(strTempTaxCode) > 0 Then
    If InStr(1, "LPTVJY", strTempTaxCode) <> 0 Then
      strTempTaxCode = "0" & strTempTaxCode
    End If
End If
```

Comment: "*If you have trouble wrapping your head around the concept, consider that all numbers have a factor of 1*" ... but then 1 (i.e. `""`, its string equivalent in this case) **should also** have a factor of 1 (just like 0 + 0 = 0), so by this logic, `InStr("","")` should be 1 as well (just like `InStr("abc","")` in your example). This isn't the case though, since `InStr("","")` returns 0. To paraphrase you, if you have trouble wrapping your head around the concept, consider that `InStr("","") = 0` means that...erm...the zero length string does not contain itself, which is ridiculously absurd.

Comment: @YinCognyto Which is why the first four words of my answer say, _All strings of **nonzero** length_. In all of your examples, you're testing a _zero-length_ string for a zero-length string. The numerical equivalent clause would be, _All nonzero numbers..._.

Comment: True, but the numerical equivalent clause would be *All non 1 numbers have a factor of 1...* (which you did **not** say, as it's obviously false), since you used multiplication by 1 - not 0 - as the numerical analogy. You didn't use the same standards when making the analogy, so the conclusion is flawed. It would have been right if you either: excluded 1 in your numerical analogy (impossible, since multiplicative identity property is true for 1 as well), or agreed that `InStr("","")` should return 1 as well, just like 1 also has a factor of 1. See my point? :)

Comment: @YinCognyto Again, I'm not saying it matches the mathematical property exactly. I specifically say, "_You can think of strings as having a **similar** identity property..._" and I added the _strings of nonzero length_ clause to guard against the empty string, which you seem to be struggling with. However, I see you've submitted your own answer, so the StackOverflow community can choose which is the best option. That's the great thing about this site. Take care.

Comment: You're right, you said similar, which is different from identical. My bad, I focused on what you said before that and didn't take into account the subtle difference. I didn't struggle with the empty string, since we all pointed out that the solution to the problem is trivial - I was just annoyed that one has to potentially implement a slower solution (e.g. an UDF) to correct this simple nonsense, when a different implementation (that wouldn't have found `""` within `"LPTVJY"`) would have made it unnecessary. I care about speed because optimization matters in the workbook I'm working on.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because, according to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function), if the string to search for (i.e. `strTempTaxCode` in this case) is zero-length, the return value of the function is **the value of the optional `start` parameter** (i.e. the index where you begin the search, in this case omitted). When ommitted, its value is **NOT** necessarily 1, but *the first character position in the string to search into* (which just happens to be 1, as the first character position in `"LPTVJY"` is incidentally the first).

This does **NOT** happen because *all strings of nonzero length, including single-character strings, contain the empty string* or the fact that the *default value of the `start` parameter is 1*, as others have noted, because they don't, and it's not. To test this try running:

```
Debug.Print InStr(2, "abc", "")   ' Returns   2, i.e. the start position
Debug.Print InStr(-13, "abc", "") ' Returns -13, i.e. the start position
Debug.Print InStr(-1, "abc", "")  ' Returns  -1, i.e. the start position
Debug.Print InStr(0, "abc", "")   ' Returns   0, i.e. the start position

Debug.Print InStr(2, "", "")      ' Returns   0, i.e. the first character position in ""
```

This won't work if the second string is non empty (it will raise an Error 5: "Invalid procedure call or argument"), unfortunately, but it's enough to prove that the return value of the function in the case of zero length strings to search for has nothing to do with them being contained in the string to search into or that the value of `start` is by default 1, but rather with the fact that the result is *whatever* the value of the `start` parameter is (even in the last test case, where it is coerced to 0 since the first character position in the empty string to search into is also 0).

The quickest solutions can be:

• for an `if..then..else` statement, use an additional condition, like [Bond](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32440462/8418085) noted:

```
If Len(strTempTaxCode) > 0 And InStr(1, "LPTVJY", strTempTaxCode) > 0 Then
  strTempTaxCode = "0" & strTempTaxCode
End if`
```

• for an assignement statement, create an UDF (user defined function) to handle it:

```
Public Function InString(Optional startposition As Long = 1, Optional searchinto As String = "", Optional searchfor As String = "", Optional comparisonmethod As VbCompareMethod = vbBinaryCompare) As Long
    If Len(searchfor) < 1 Then InString = -1 Else InString = InStr(startposition, searchinto, searchfor, comparisonmethod)
End Function
```

Other presented solutions are slower. The first of these two above ran 1 million times in 0.03 s, the same as the one-conditional `InStr`, while the second ran in 0.30 s. As you can see, just because Microsoft thought that it should return the `start` value even when it's plain obvious that `""` is **NOT** contained in a string like `"LPTVJY"`, the users have to sometimes use an UDF that runs 10 times slower than the original function. The funny thing is that, just like with a lie that becomes truth when repeated enough, some people even think this is how it should be because that's how it's implemented.

Comment: Start, as you quoted, is _optional_. If omitted, search begins at the first characted position of string 1, which is effectively 1. That's no coincidence. Also, in each of the examples you gave, you specified an explicit start position, not proving (or disproving) anything I wrote. When start is specified, it is indeed returned as is, if string2 is empty, as per the documentation and my answer.

Comment: You said, and I quote: *In VB, the strings are 1 based. Because of that, when omitted, the default value for start (the start position to search from) is 1*. That's not the case for `Debug.Print InStr("","")`, where despite string2 being empty and not using an explicit `start` parameter, it doesn't return the default 1 as per your statement, but 0, i.e. the the first character position in an empty string. That's exactly why I included the last test case scenario above. I don't mean to offend or look for faults where there aren't, by the way - just to be clear.

Answer (score 2):

In VB, the strings are 1 based. Because of that, when omitted, the default value for *start* (the start position to search from) is 1.

When *string2* (the one you search for) is zero length or nothing, InStr returns *start* <sup>*1)</sup>, which is in your case 1.

<sup>*1)</sup> [MSDN documentation on InStr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx)

The phrase *as none of the characters from `"LPTVJY"` are within `strTempTaxCode`* suggests you misinterpreted the function. It searches string2 within string1. The documentation mentions a lot of edge cases and what the function returns in that case. However, the function is likely much simpler than that and could be written as a nested loop, roughly as follows (only way more optimized internally).

```
For s = start to Len(string1) - start
  For c = 1 to Len(string2)

    ' Out of characters. There is no match.
    If c+s-1 > Len(string1) then Return 0

    ' Mismatch. Try again for the next value of 's'.
    If SubStr(string1, c+s-1) <> SubStr(string2, c) then Exit For

  Next
Next

' If you get here, a match is found at position s.
Return s
```

Please be so kind as to treat the code above as pseudo code. It's merely for explanation, and I have no idea if it actually works.

Comment: If in VB the strings are 1 based and `InStr` searches String2 in String 1 with the OP "misinterpreting the function" when expecting a *practically* correct result from it, then why `InStr("","")` returns 0 instead of 1? After all, in VB the strings are 1 based, and the `Start` value is 1 by default... The exception of `""` from the rule (or the fact that it doesn't return a value less than 1 to handle the case) is both illogical and a practical inconvenience. A simple one line UDF for this case increased the running time from 0.03s to 0.28s if executed 1 million times. Yours ran in about 4s.

Comment: I didn't implement the actual InStr function, so I can't be sure what the reason is, but I imagine 1 is considered an illegal result for zero length strings, because the function returns either a (valid) index, or 0 if it can't. 1 is not a valid index for empty strings.

Comment: You're close - it's only about the value of the start parameter, which is coerced to the first character position in the string to search into (i.e. 0) for empty such strings, as I explained in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59340191/8418085). Either way, the implementation is faulty, because "LPTVJY" doesn't contain "", simple as that. It would have made sense if that index was used for further searches that began at the last position in the string to search into (as it's the case in other programming languages), but as far as I know, in VBA it's not the case. Thanks for replying ;)

Comment: I didn't write that LPTVJY contains "". That was Bond. Also, the code presented was just to give some insight in how a function like this can work. As I wrote it is in no way optimized, nor do I claim that this is _the_ way it works internally or the way it should work. That value for the start parameter only applies when string1 is not empty. If it is, the function returns 0, regardless of the start parameter you specify. Btw, when I said 'misunderstood', it's because OP seemed to expect that the characters of string1 would be searched in string2, at least that was how it was written.

Comment: My bad, it's indeed how the OP wrote it - now I misunderstood things, apparently. I retract my statements regarding your 'misunderstood' use - I can edit my answer accordingly, if it bothers you. And yes, you didn't write that "LPTVJY" contains "" statement, but then, I wasn't referring to you on that, so no harm done. I know that your function is just a sample, what I meant was that the code needed to correct the faulty InStr implementation is much slower - including mine. Apart from that, the fact that your code is slower is not a lie. Here, I was just stating the obvious, not criticizing.

Answer (score 1):

Only solution I find to avoid finding a nullstring was to change the to something I was not expecting to find to obtain 0

InStr("abcd", IIf(txt = "", "~", txt))

This way I get the 0 of string not found I'm after